# PHP PDO fetch method returns "wrong" index for SQLite views

Tags: php, sqlite, view, pdo

a simple:

```
$row = $stmt->fetch();
```

returns an array $row having, as indexes, the field names. If we are selecting records from a VIEW instead of a TABLE, however, the indexes are in the form `tablename.fieldname` and not just `fieldname`

Why? Is this a bug?

Comment: If your VIEW or subquery merges multiple tables (it wouldn't hurt to include crucial information), then the result array keys are usually qualified.

Comment: No, the view is just something like:
CREATE VIEW test as select id_user, name_user from users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_name.html) says:

> The name of a result column is the value of the "AS" clause for that column, if there is an AS clause. If there is no AS clause then the name of the column is unspecified and may change from one release of SQLite to the next.

So if you use the column names to access the values, you should explicitly give them a name with AS.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, it is still not understandable why a query WITHOUT AS returns field as name if we are querying a TABLE and table.field as name if we are querying a VIEW.

Comment: It's unspecified. SQLite uses whatever it feels like using.

Comment: Yes, still it seems a non-sense approach. Anyway I will mark as correct your answer since you pointed out the reason.